# what is the alternate way for CacheManager.setName(String name)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

when we upgrade ehcache 2.7.2 to 2.10.6 I am getting compile time error at `cm.setName(cmName + "." + cm.hashCode());`

public HibernateCacheJmxRegister(JmxSupport jmxSupport) throws  MalformedObjectNameException {

```
      // Register the ehcache with JMX
      for (Object obj : CacheManager.ALL_CACHE_MANAGERS) {
          CacheManager cm = (CacheManager) obj;

          String cmName = cm.getName();
          if (cmName.startsWith("interact."))
              continue; // Don't register caches

          // If the cache manager is from a common ehcache configuration, then make the name
          // unique by adding the hash code of the config manager.
          if (cmName.startsWith("common.")) {
              cm.setName(cmName + "." + cm.hashCode());
          }

          ManagementService.registerMBeans(
                  cm, jmxSupport.getPrimaryMBeanServer(), false, false, false, true);
      }
}
```

could you please provide me alternative way to do this.

Comment: hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the information about compile error you are getting.

Comment: compile error is : The method setName(String) is undefined for the type CacheManager